# How to set the number at status bar

Tags: android

I want to show the number as text on status bar in android. I have set the icons but i want to set the number which is dynamic. Is it possible to do that.

```
//Create the Notification
Notification notification = new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning, "Battery Indicator", System.currentTimeMillis());
//Create a PendingIntent to do something when the user clicks on the Notification
//Normally this would be something in your own app
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), BatteryIndicator.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

//Add the detail to the Notification
notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(),"Battery Indicator", "Charge level: " + batteryRemaining , pi);

//Display the Notification
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: Problem solved by adding notification.number = batteryRemaining;

Answer (score 0):

Android [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) (if you mean this class) does not support any `setText` or the like. I would propose to create a custom component overriding `onDraw(Canvas)`. You can call `super.onDraw` to do the most of the work and then use `Canvas.drawText` to draw the number over in the center (use `View.getWidth` and `getHeight` to find where this center is).

Answer (score 0):

use notification.number=value;